# Noetherian ring does not imply artinian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal M and there exists a non-maximal prime ideal of R, then 
Prove that $M^{n+1} \subset M^n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$(strict subset) 
i.e. R is not artinian.

How can you use existence of non-maximal prime ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Nakayama, if there is some $n \geq 0$ such that $M^{n+1}=M^n$, then $M^n=0$. In particular, for every prime ideal $P$ of $A$, if $x \in M$, $x^n=0 \in P$ so $x \in P$, thus $P=M$.

Comment: Do you assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with 1? I'm trying to grasp how would be if $R$ is non-commutative or has no multiplicative identity. Would you just elaborate on this? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @sera When one talks about Noetherian local ring, it is most likely that he is talking about something in commutative algebra.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Oh, I'm not aware of that.... Thanks

Comment: @sera For noncommutative rings, this formulation of Nakayama's lemma is still valid, and it is still true that any prime ideal must contain any nilpotent ideal.  So, all the reasoning in this post is still valid for noncommutative rings, after minor rewording.